# Convert a HTML input tag to Dojo TextBox using java script

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am generating 4 input fields from inside my Java Script. But now I want to use dojo TextBox dijit to take input.
How can I convert my input tags to dojo TextBox?

This is the present Code...

```
var container = document.createElement("span");
domClass.add(container, "Class name");
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.name = "textinput";
domClass.add(input, "Some Class name");
container.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/TextBox.html

Comment: How are your `input` fields being generated? All you need to do is programmatically create the `dijit/form/TextBox` widgets instead (and place them somewhere of course). The link @KostiaShiian provided should give you enough information to clue you in on how to create these widgets.

Comment: @Default.... I added my current code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that you've required *"dojo/dom-class"* in order to use it to add classes to your DOM nodes. Now you'll want to require *"dijit/form/TextBox"* as well. You will need some DOM node to put your new TextBox widgets in, something like `<div id="input_container"></div>`. When you have that, creating them and inserting them is as simple as:

```
new TextBox({
   name: "textinput",
   // Additional properties...
}, "input_container");
```

This will create a new *dijit/form/TextBox* widget and place it in the `div` with "input_container" as its id. You don't have to immediately place your widget in the DOM structure as I am showing, as you can see [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Zh8/28/), you can also assign your new TextBox widget to a variable that you can place where you want later.

On a side note, I see you are using `document.createElement()` and the native `appendChild()` methods. These are not standard per browser, so you may end up with some odd issues between browsers down the line by relying on these methods. Dojo provides a nice [dojo/dom-construct](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/dom-construct.html#dojo-dom-construct) module that provides similar methods for you, and handles different browser implementations on its own (so you don't have to worry about it).

Comment: Thnx that really helped me.